# Valgrind not showing code lines, code compiled with debugger option

Tags: c, valgrind

I am compiling my code with the following Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
FL_DEBUG = -g -Wall
OBJ = src/main.o src/hash.o

hash_me: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(FL_DEBUG) -o hash_me $(OBJ)

src/main.o: src/main.c
    $(CC) $(FL_DEBUG) -c src/main.c -o src/main.o

src/hash.o: src/hash.c
    $(CC) $(FL_DEBUG) -c src/hash.c -o src/hash.o
```

so, I use the -g option to be able to track my mistakes when I debug the code with valgrind. But when I run valgrind, using this command:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes ./hash_me file.txt
```

it is still not showing me the lines, where my errors are. I don't see what am I missing here. So it looks like:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2146==    at 0x10000ACFB: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:435)
==2146==    by 0x100001152: parseFile (in ./hash_me)
==2146==    by 0x100001713: hashFiles (in ./hash_me)
==2146==    by 0x100000F19: main (in ./hash_me)
==2146==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==2146==    at 0x10000951B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
```

Comment: Try a `make -B` to force everything to be re-compiled and try again ?

Comment: I tried that but it is not changing anything :/

Comment: It looks like you have two different executables, `hash` and `hash_me` ?

Comment: Sorry I dont have, It was a typo while I was changing the file names for publication reasons, I am sorry for the confusion

Comment: Not reproducible here with your exact Makefile, [see](http://pastebin.com/jtDyQX5t).

Comment: OK - please don't ever post approximations or edits of your code or tool/program output - copy and paste from the actual source without any changes, otherwise it just causes confusion.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "not reproducible with your exact makefile" ?

Comment: @PaulR: Heh, not quite. There's nothing wrong with altering/trimming/tailoring the code before posting. In fact, we highly encourage that. It's just that you have to *test what you post*. Naturally, before posting... ;)

Comment: @malajedala: sorry, but what do you mean by "what do you mean"? It's just a plain english sentence. Could you explain what's causing your confusion?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: yes, by "edits" I meant changing details on-the-fly within the code you post.

Comment: However I got the point, sorry again. stiill not helping me for the problem ;)

Comment: Are you building on OS X?

Comment: I took your makefile, added some C code, ran make, ran valgrind, and your problem is not visible..